# MySQL SELECT Query: Add 28 days to the last date of a financial quarter

Tags: mysql, select, case

I am wanting to add 28 days to the last day of a quarter.

I currently have the following to determine the Quarter period, how can I then add 28 days to the last date of the last month in the quarter.

```
CASE    -- Results:  2011-Q4 (Financial Year-Qtr)
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN concat((YEAR(T5.date_purchased) - 1), '-', 'Q3')
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN concat((YEAR(T5.date_purchased) - 1), '-', 'Q4')
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN concat((YEAR(T5.date_purchased) - 0), '-', 'Q1')
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN concat((YEAR(T5.date_purchased) - 0), '-', 'Q2')
END AS FYrQtr,
```

I do not need to account for anything unusual, simply the 28th of the next month in the next quarter.

I have tried the following, but of course that adds 28 days to the order date, not the financial qtr.  (I do not need the time)

```
CASE    --  Results:  2012-06-20 07:20:07  not  2012-07-28
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN date_add(T5.date_purchased, Interval 28 day) 
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN date_add(T5.date_purchased, Interval 28 day)
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN date_add(T5.date_purchased, Interval 28 day)
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 10  AND 12  THEN date_add(T5.date_purchased, Interval 28 day)
    END AS FRangeQtrBAS,
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the year from the purchasedate and concat it with the know end of  quarter month and day:

```
CASE    
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN date_add(CONCAT(YEAR(T5.date_purchased), '-03-31'), Interval 28 day) 
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN date_add(CONCAT(YEAR(T5.date_purchased), '-06-30'), Interval 28 day)
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN date_add(CONCAT(YEAR(T5.date_purchased), '-09-30'), Interval 28 day)
    WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 10  AND 12  THEN date_add(CONCAT(YEAR(T5.date_purchased), '-12-31'), Interval 28 day)
END AS FRangeQtrBAS
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had to make a slight adjustment as December to February was a different date period.  `WHEN MONTH(T5.date_purchased) BETWEEN 10  AND 12  THEN date_add(CONCAT(YEAR(T5.date_purchased) + 1, '+01-31'), Interval 28 day)`  It works fabulously, thank you.